# How to add image to specific Media Collection Conversion with Laravel-medialibrary?

Tags: laravel, laravel-medialibrary

I have two input image in my form, and one registerMediaConversions :

```js
 public function registerMediaConversions(Media $media = null) : void
    {
        $this->addMediaConversion('big')
            ->performOnCollections('category-cover');

        $this->addMediaConversion('medium')
            ->crop(Manipulations::CROP_CENTER, 645, 300)
            ->performOnCollections('category-cover');

        $this->addMediaConversion('small')
            ->crop(Manipulations::CROP_CENTER, 300, 300)
            ->performOnCollections('category-cover');

        $this->addMediaConversion('thumb')
            ->width(100)
            ->sharpen(10)
            ->performOnCollections('category-cover');

    }
```

i want the first input do the big, medium and thumb conversions , and the second input do the small conversion, is this possible with laravel media-library ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. To do that you must define collections as same as your input in your model. For example:

```
public function registerMediaCollections(): void
{
    $this->addMediaCollection('category-cover');
    $this->addMediaCollection('categories-another-collection');
}
```

Then You need to register media conversion for 2 different collections as follows:

```
public function registerMediaConversions(Media $media = null) : void
{
    $this->addMediaConversion('big')
        ->performOnCollections('category-cover');

    $this->addMediaConversion('medium')
        ->crop(Manipulations::CROP_CENTER, 645, 300)
        ->performOnCollections('category-cover');

    $this->addMediaConversion('small')
        ->crop(Manipulations::CROP_CENTER, 300, 300)
        ->performOnCollections('categories-another-collection');

    $this->addMediaConversion('thumb')
        ->width(100)
        ->sharpen(10)
        ->performOnCollections('category-cover');
}
```

Let say, in your controller taking 2 field request as follows:

```
    $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
        'files1' => 'required',
        'files1.*' => 'image|mimes:jpg,jpeg,png,gif|max:2048',
        'files2' => 'required',
        'files2.*' => 'image|mimes:jpg,jpeg,png,gif|max:2048',
    ]);
```

Then you can able to save those 2 types of file by:

```
    if ($request->hasFile('files1')) {
        $fileAdders = $categoryModel->addMultipleMediaFromRequest(['images'])
            ->each(function ($fileAdder) {
                $fileAdder->toMediaCollection('category-cover');
            });
    }

    if ($request->hasFile('files2')) {
        $fileAdders = $categoryModel->addMultipleMediaFromRequest(['images'])
            ->each(function ($fileAdder) {
                $fileAdder->toMediaCollection('categories-another-collection');
            });
    }
```

At the end the files1 input request will use big, medium and thumb conversions based on collection(category-cover) and files2 input request will use only small conversion based on collection('categories-another-collection')